# Sequelize failing to create a table with the error "Executing (default): SELECT 1+1 AS result"

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

Thank you for taking the time to help out. When running my server I am getting a message "Executing (default): SELECT 1+1 AS result". My tables are not being created. How do I fix this error? I am using the technologies MySQL, Sequelize, JavaScript, Express, and Node.

****Connection.js (I have checked the .env and the information is accurate)****

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
require('dotenv').config();

const sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env.DB_NAME, process.env.DB_USER, process.env.DB_PW, {
      host: 'localhost',
      dialect: 'mysql',
      port: 3306
});

module.exports = sequelize;
```

**Schema.sql**

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS events_db;

CREATE DATABASE events_db;
```

**Customer model**

```
const { DataTypes, Model } = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = require('../config/connection');

class Customer extends Model {}

Customer.init(
    {
        uuid: {
            type: DataTypes.UUID,
            defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV1,
            primaryKey: true,
            allowNull: false,
            unique: true,
        },
        name: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
            validate: {
                notEmpty: true,
            }
        },
        phone: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
            unique: true,
            validate: {
                notEmpty: true,
                is: /^[\+]?[(]?\d{3}[)]?[-\s\.]?\d{3}[-\s\.]?\d{4,6}$/im
            }
        },
        email: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
            unique: true,
            validate: {
                isEmail: true
            }
        },
        address: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
            unique: true,
            validate: {
                notEmpty: true
            }
        }
    },
    {
        sequelize,
        freezeTableName: true,
        underscored: true,
        modelName: 'customer'
    }
);

module.exports = Customer;
```

**Model index.js**

```
const Customer = require('./Customer');
const Event = require('./Event');
const EventType = require('./EventType');
const Reservation = require('./Reservation');

Customer.hasMany(Reservation, {foreignKey: { allowNull: false }});
Event.hasMany(Reservation, {foreignKey: { allowNull: false }});
Event.hasOne(EventType, {foreignKey: { allowNull: false }});
Event.hasOne(Customer, {foreignKey: { allowNull: false }});

module.exports = { Customer, Event, EventType, Reservation };
```

**Server.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const sequelize = require('./config/connection');

const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;

const routes = require('./routes');

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));

app.use(routes);

sequelize.sync({ force: false }).then(() => {
    app.listen(PORT, () => {
        console.log(`App is listening on port ${PORT}`);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imported models into server.js file. Did not need to call the variable. This allowed for sequelize to "see" my models. When implementing a controller or GraphQL, this import can be removed.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).